Where did I go wrong in calculating the vector area of ​the hemisphere in my solution to Griffith Exercise 1.61?
Exercise 1.61 from David. J. Griffiths's book:
Integral
$$
\vec a \equiv \int_S d \vec a
$$
Sometimes called the vector area of ​​a surface $S$. Obviously, if $S$ happens to be flat, then | $a$ | is just the ordinary (scalar) area. Find the vector area of ​​a hemispherical surface of radius $R$.
I did this: $\hat r,\hat z,\hat x ,\hat y $are all unit vectors,
$d \vec a =R^2 \sin \theta d \theta d \phi \hat{ r }$. Let the surface be the northern hemisphere. The components $\hat{ x }$ and $\hat{ y }$ obviously integrate to zero, and the relationship between $\hat r$ and $\hat z$ is shown in the figure,
so
$$
\vec a =\int R^2 \sin \theta \frac{1}{\cos \theta} d \theta d \phi \hat{ z }
$$
But the answer is $$a =\int R^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta d \theta d \phi \hat{ z }$$
Where did I go wrong?

The reason you ran into issues with your method is because the unit vectors by definition have length one, and so the relationship you've written between them is simply incorrect. For an easy way to see why, consider that what you've written is the same as $1=1/\cos\theta$, which is not true for arbitrary $\theta$.
Instead, you should start with the actual vector $\mathbf{r}$, and then use your method to decompose it into its components along each of the Cartesian directions. Then, you can utilize the fact that $\hat{\mathbf{r}}=\mathbf{r}/r$ to find a form for the unit vector.
Lets find $\hat{\mathbf{r}}$:
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbf{r}&=x\hat{\mathbf{x}}+y\hat{\mathbf{y}}+z\hat{\mathbf{z}}\\
&=r\sin\theta\cos\phi\,\hat{\mathbf{x}}+r\sin\theta\sin\phi\,\hat{\mathbf{y}}+r\cos\theta\,\hat{\mathbf{z}}\\
\hat{\mathbf{r}}=\frac{\mathbf{r}}{r}&=\sin\theta\cos\phi\,\hat{\mathbf{x}}+\sin\theta\sin\phi\,\hat{\mathbf{y}}+\cos\theta\,\hat{\mathbf{z}}
\end{align*}$$
As you said, the $x$ and $y$ components will integrate to zero, so we can substitute $\cos\theta\,\hat{\mathbf{z}}$ inside the integral.

I treated $\hat{r}$ as if decomposing a force, forgetting that they are unit vectors. Thank you for your detailed and clear explanation.
